# Background video is preventing the login screen to appear in Cordova app in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I have developed a cordova app and built in IOS. The app has a background video which will run in the background of the app. The first screen of the app is a login screen. But when the app is launched, the video is loaded and started playing but the login screen does not appear. After tapping the video and dragging a little downwards, the login screen appears. Why is it happening? It is not happening in android. Please give suggestion.

This is our code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Leader Board</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-demos.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link href="css/jquery.modal.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://rawgithub.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/v0.1.1/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css" />
        
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/jquery/jquery-ui/1.10.4/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script id="mobile-datepicker"
        src="https://rawgithub.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/v0.1.1/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>


<body>

    <video width="100%" muted autoplay loop style="height:100vh;object-fit:cover;opacity:.7;position: fixed;" poster="images/appbackimg.png">
      <source src="images/appbackvid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <div data-role="page" id="one" class="transback haswowsec">

        <!--<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="hdrtop">
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></div>
    </div> /header -->
        <div class="loginupsec wow zoomIn">
            <img src="images/livelogo.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content loginmainsec loginsection">
            <form method="post" id="loginForm">
                <div class="mainsecsn mainlogin wow fadeInUp">
                    <h2 class="newfrmhding">Login</h2>
                    <div class="allfrmfield">
                        <div class="ui-field-contain app_input frmfldbkstyl">
                            <span class="icntst"><img src="images/frmmessage.png" alt="" /></span>
                            <input type="email" name="mynm" id="mynm" class="transtxtbox required"
                                placeholder="Enter Email" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-field-contain app_input frmfldbkstyl" style="margin-bottom:0;">
                            <span class="icntst"><img src="images/frmpasswrd.png" alt="" /></span>
                            <span class="loginpassbox"><input type="password" name="mypass" id="mypass" class="transtxtbox required"
                                placeholder="Enter Password" /></span>
                            <span class="logeye"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showpass_login"><img src="images/eyepass.png" alt="" /></a></span>
                        </div>
                        <!--<p class="frgpas" style="text-align:right;"><a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a></p>-->
                        <p id="loginloader" style="display:none;text-align:center;"><img src="images/loader.png"></p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" id="mylogin" class="allfrmbutn" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="signupbox">Don't have an account? <a href="#register" data-transition="slide">Sign up</a></p>
                </div>

            </form>
            
            
        </div><!-- /content -->



    </div><!-- /page one -->
    
    <div data-role="page" id="register" class="transback haswowsec">

        <div class="loginupsec wow zoomIn">
            <img src="images/livelogo.png" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="padding-top:60px;">
            <form id="addschlusrForm">
                <div class="mainsecsn mainlogin wow fadeInUp">
                    <h2 class="newfrmhding">Company Sign Up</h2>
                    <div class="allfrmfield">

                        <div class="ui-field-contain app_input frmfldbkstyl">
                            <span class="icntst"><img src="images/frmuser.png" alt="" /></span>
                            <input type="text" class="transtxtbox required" name="std_name" id="std_name"
                                placeholder="Name" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-field-contain app_input frmfldbkstyl">
                            <span class="icntst"><img src="images/frmmessage.png" alt="" /></span>
                            <input type="email" class="transtxtbox required" name="std_email" id="std_email"
                                placeholder="Email" />
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="ui-field-contain app_input frmfldbkstyl">
                            <span class="icntst"><img src="images/frmbuliding.png" alt="" /></span>
                            <input type="text" class="transtxtbox required" name="std_comp" id="std_comp"
                                placeholder="Your Company" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-field-contain app_input frmfldbkstyl">
                            <span class="icntst"><img src="images/frmpasswrd.png" alt="" /></span>
                            <span class="loginpassbox"><input type="password" class="transtxtbox required" placeholder="Password" name="std_pass" id="std_pass" /></span>
                            <span class="logeye"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showpass_signup"><img src="images/eyepass.png" alt="" /></a></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-field-contain app_input frmfldbkstyl">
                            <span class="icntst"><img src="images/frmpasswrd.png" alt="" /></span>
                            <span class="loginpassbox"><input type="password" class="transtxtbox required mycnpassstd"
                                placeholder="Confirm Password" name="std_con_pass" id="std_con_pass" /></span>
                            <span class="logeye"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showpass_signup2"><img src="images/eyepass.png" alt="" /></a></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-field-contain app_input frmfldbkstyl">
                            <span class="icntst"><img src="images/code.png" alt="" /></span>
                            <input type="text" class="transtxtbox" name="code" id="code"
                                placeholder="Promo Code" />
                        </div>

                        <p id="studentaddloader" style="display:none;text-align:center;"><img src="images/loader.png">
                        </p>

                        <input type="submit" value="Register" id="addmyusrbtn" class="allfrmbutn" />
                    </div>
                    <p class="signupbox">Already have an account? <a href="#one" data-transition="slide">Login here</a></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /page register -->
    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

The video is in the "Video" tag.